# Is There a More Fluent jQuery Event Handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a jQuery selector chain like this:

```
var toObject = function () { return this; };
var doAction = function () { /*do action*/ };

$('.selector').map(toObject).each(doAction);
```

Is it possible to write this same logic but using an event filter like this:

```
/*onChange() doesn't exist. I made it up as an example.*/
$('.selector').onChange().map(toObject).each(doAction);
```

It's kind of a blend of Promises and Fluent Selectors. The onChange would basically be a never ending filter that can always return more items as the change event is triggered.

Functionally I know I can achieve this by doing the following:

```
var toObject = function (obj) { return obj; };
var doAction = function (obj) { /*do action*/ };

$('.selector').change(function () { doAction(toObject(this));});
```

So basically I'm just asking is there a way to achieve that functionality in a more "fluent" way.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. Do you mean that the `map(toObject).each(doAction)` part should be triggered by the event?

Comment: @abl basically. I know I can do this `$('.selector').change(function() { doAction.apply(toObject.apply(this)); });` I could also make those methods take a parameter so I don't have the .apply(). So it is more a question of style than functionality.

Comment: but what is the problem behind the question? perhaps there's a better/clearer way to do it.

Comment: Thank you guys for your questions. I've modified my question to try to make it more clear what I'm asking. Please let me know if it still isn't clear.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think your real question is whether you can program event handling in a fluent way - `onEvent().doThing()` - instead of by passing parameters - `onEvent(doThing)`. If that's the case, then maybe you simplify the question by leaving out either the `toObject` or the `doAction` method.

Comment: @abl Kind of. I'd like it to integrate with the rest of jQuery's fluent methods if possible. Otherwise I feel that what you are suggesting would be similar to $.when().done(); which is great but not exactly what I was looking for in this case. Maybe it just isn't a good question and I'm being too OCD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery event handlers are used in the following way:

```
// Let's call this "coding style A"

$("selector").onSomeEvent(doSomething);

// With promises:
someAsyncProcess().done(doSomething);
```

Where `doSomething` is a function. You basically make event handlers and pass them around as parameters. I think that part of the rationale behind that is that the event methods can return a jQuery object so you can chain handler assignments:

```
$("selector").onSomeEvent(doSomething).onSomeOtherEvent(doAnotherThing);
```

If I may give my opinion, this is readable enough for me. It also feels natural to pass handlers as parameters.

You're asking if it might be possible to write handlers in another way, even if it's just for consistency with the coding style of the rest of the program:

```
// We're going to call this "coding style B"
$("selector").onSomeEvent().doSomething();
```

Now that reads nice, but it has its own problems. To begin with, the `doSomething()` function that we're using in B cannot be the same `doSomething()` that we were using in A. In A, `doSomething()` was an event handler. In B, `doSomething()` is executed synchronously at the time we attach the event, so it cannot be the actual event handler (as long as *event handler* means a function that gets executed when the event occurs).

Besides, note that on A the `onSomeEvent()` is probably part of some generic API (just like jQuery's `click()`, `change()`, `on()`, etc. are) while the handler `doSomething()` may contain application-specific logic. It's not straightforward to achieve the same effect in B, given that the generic `onSomeEvent()` should return an object that already has a property named `doSomething`.

So while it may be possible to achieve this coding style, it would probably do more harm than good. The simple, almost-natural-language line that we've just seen would require a substantial amount of less intuitive code in other places, not only in the library/framework but also in the applications that use it.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. I don't fully agree with all your conclusions, but I can't argue with your cogency and completeness. Thank you for taking the time to think through this with me and give a thoughtful answer.